# QR reader for Ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Linux / Ubuntu and am enjoying the challenge of learning how to use it. I am presently stuck on how to install a QR-reader.  It would seem that QrQt is a good one but I can't download it.  I have been to elsewhere on this forum and there are answers but they are too technical.  I am able to use the Terminal and am looking for **EXACT** code that I need to write in the Terminal to enable me to download and use the QrQt.  Is there anyone here patient and kind enough to help me?  If so, I would be very grateful.  Many thanks, Duncan, Scotland, UK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and add this PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:qr-tools-developers/qr-tools-stable
```

Update your sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install qtqr
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I really appreciate your help - both your, and the first answer worked very nicely thanks. Once again, much appreciated. Duncan

Answer (score 2):

QtQR is a QR reader that works using your webcam.

You can install it simply with:

```
sudo apt-get install qtqr
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I really appreciate your help - both your, and the second answers worked very nicely thanks. Once again, much appreciated. Duncan

Comment: @Duncan If this worked for you click the check mark on the left to thank the user and let others easily find the information.

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 16.04, there is also the [zbar-tools package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/zbar-tools) which provides command-line QR readers:

> ```
> zbarcam (1)          - scan and decode bar codes from a video device
> zbarimg (1)          - scan and decode bar codes from image file(s)
> ```

To read the content of a QR image file:

```
zbarimg Your_QR_Image.png
```

More info on [their website](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/about.html)

Comment: Thank you. Your time, information and expertise is greatly appreciated.